# Save data into keychain using Shell Script

Tags: ios, swift, bash, security, keychain

I am trying to save some static data into keychain using ShellScript. But when I try fetch that data via native swift code it does not provided the data. My code is as follow:

ShellScript:

```sh
service_name="MyKeychainService"

# Specify the account name for the keychain item
account_name="MyAccount"

# Specify the string data you want to save
string_data="YourSecretString"

# Save the string data into the keychain
security add-generic-password -a "$account_name" -s "$service_name" -w "$string_data" -U
```

iOS native Swift Code:

```swift
func retrieveDataFromKeychain(service: String, account: String) -> String? {
    var query = [
        kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
        kSecAttrService: service,
        kSecAttrAccount: account,
        kSecReturnData: kCFBooleanTrue as Any,
        kSecMatchLimit: kSecMatchLimitOne
    ] as [String: Any]

    var data: AnyObject?
    let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &data)

    if status == errSecSuccess {
        if let retrievedData = data as? Data {
            return String(data: retrievedData, encoding: .utf8)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Usage:

```swift
let service = "MyKeychainService"
let account = "MyAccount"

if let retrievedData = retrieveDataFromKeychain(service: service, account: account) {
    print("Retrieved data from keychain: \(retrievedData)")
} else {
    print("Failed to retrieve data from keychain")
}
```

Comment: I don't see any bash code in your question.

Comment: “I am trying to save…”, well someone has to ask the obvious question. Have you verified that the data is saved properly?

Comment: Readers need a way to reconstruct your problem else everyone gets to play 20 questions. (Don't expect readers to goto external sites to understand your problem, so convert that image into plain text and format properly). Read about [mcve] but also read the section [How to turn a bad script into a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) on the `bash-info` page. Good luck.

Comment: @user1934428, added script code now, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, as I am running into simulator, I don't know how can I verify that it is save properly or not, that's why I am trying to fetch from swift code to check.

Comment: How can you run a shell script on iOS?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson,  I am writing this into Xcode's Build phase -> Run Script 
so,it runs automatically when we build the project.

Comment: A shell script run during the build phase will save data into the keychain of the Mac that is building the app. When you run Swift code in your app it is accessing the keychain of the iOS device. There is no way to add data into the keychain of the iOS device during the build phase

Comment: @Peter although you're running on a simulator, you're not going to find your stored value in the Keychain or through bash scripts. Use Swift/Objective-C code to query the Keychain instead (like in your code). Adding it via bash and then attempting to read it from app is impossible (for iOS simulator apps). You have to also add it in the app